# How to walk the Kernel's VMA?

Tags: linux, kernel, memory

I'm writing a kernel module that finds and parses the VM_EXEC pages of a process. This is doable through walking the virtual memory of the process, similar to what `/proc/$PID/maps` does. However, I also want to extend this to the linux kernel itself, but I don't know where to begin.

How would I enumerate which pages are assigned to the kernel and which pages are assigned to any kernel modules currently running?

Comment: Perhaps this would be better on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Torger597 Indeed, programming questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To walk the VMAs for the kernel space you need to use the `init_mm` variable of type `mm_struct` in the same way that you are probably already doing with the `task_struct active_mm` field.

As for the second part of the question it may be possible to distinguish between kernel code and module code by listing the modules and looking at the fields `module_core`, `init_text_size` and `core_text_size` of the `module` structure.

But I'm not sure you will be able to distinguish between pages allocated from a kernel modules and those allocated from the kernel unless you provide the modules with a different version of kmalloc (possibly during the linking phase.)

Comment: With regards to the first part, `init_mm` has a `.mmap` member, but it always seems to be NULL. Is there any other way to get at the VMA of the kernel memory?

Comment: hmm I would have expected it to be used. No idea for the moment as to where you could look for it instead.